# Is there a way to get higher-root symbols to render correctly when rooting a fraction?

Tags: support, mathjax

Given a root symbol that becomes tall:

$$\sqrt[N]{\dfrac{\lambda}{3^e}}$$

The `N` is now rendered disproportionately small.

Does a fix exist?  Is this a bug?

---

*edit: as a follow-up to the accepted answer, [here is a reference on font size and style setting](http://www.combinatorics.net/weblib/options/style.html)*

Comment: A big exponent there would be very very weird!

Comment: If you ever find yourself in Australia, please be careful about using "root" as a verb.

Comment: See [Nice-looking p-th roots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49043/9954) at TeX.SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try

`text{\sqrt[\large N]{\dfrac{\lambda}{3^e}}`:
$\quad\displaystyle\sqrt[\large N]{\dfrac{\lambda}{3^e}}$

or `text{\sqrt[\Large N]{\dfrac{\lambda}{3^e}}`:
$\quad\displaystyle\sqrt[\Large N]{\dfrac{\lambda}{3^e}}$

but `\sqrt[\huge N]{\dfrac{\lambda}{3^e}}`:
$\quad\displaystyle\sqrt[\huge N]{\dfrac{\lambda}{3^e}}$

starts to look very odd.

**Afterthought:**

I was looking at the larger indices and they looked kind of crowded to the radical. I think these look even better:

`text{\sqrt[\raise{2pt}{\large N}]{\dfrac{\lambda}{3^e}}`:
$\quad\displaystyle\sqrt[\raise{2pt}{\large N}]{\dfrac{\lambda}{3^e}}\quad\Large\star$

or `text{\sqrt[\raise{2pt}{\Large N}]{\dfrac{\lambda}{3^e}}`:
$\quad\displaystyle\sqrt[\raise{2pt}{\Large N}]{\dfrac{\lambda}{3^e}}$

I think the starred one looks best

Comment: Can you please add the source via `ticks`

Comment: Agreed that there is a limit

Comment: **ProTip!** I found you can right-click on TeX and get a menu that will display the source.  It's custom for this site!

Comment: @NewAlexandria: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that... I just assumed people knew how to see the source. Thanks for mentioning that!

Comment: I wish I could upvote a second time.  Nice edit.